# do math operation on a column based on the certain and same rows of the other column (groupby unique values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below and need to write a Python code to do the following for me:

Based on the following instructions, I need to do a math operation on column C. So, I need to take the last two values of column C (12.33 and 43.90), which are based on the repetitive rows of column A (e.g., C1), compare the two values with the rest of the other 4 values, take the value that is closest to the rest of the values (i.e. **12.33**), and then divide column C by that values which will result in column D. and repeat this operation for the rest of the rows.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
A     B       C        D
---   ---     ---      ---
C1    b1      10.2     (10.2/12.33)
C1    b2      11.2     (11.2/12.33)
C1    b3      13.12    (13.12/12.33)
C1    b4      11.90    (11.90/12.33)
C1    b5      **12.33**    (12.33/12.33)
C1    b6      43.90     -

V2    b1      54.08   (54.08/36.23)
V2    b2      42.99   (42.99/36.23)
V2    b3      43.65   (43.65/36.23)
V2    b4      **36.23**  (36.23/36.23)
V2    b5      12.23    -
```

Comment: Give a fully reproducible example with expected output as well. Also mentioning what you tried and why it didn't work will be good

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
def my_func(g):
    if len(g) <= 2:
        return g

    a, b = g["C"].tail(2)

    v1 = np.mean(np.abs(g["C"][:-2] - a))
    v2 = np.mean(np.abs(g["C"][:-2] - b))

    g["D"] = g["C"] / min((v1, a), (v2, b))[1]
    g["D"][-2:] = np.where(g["D"][-2:] == 1, g["D"][-2:], np.nan)

    return g


df = df.groupby("A", group_keys=False).apply(my_func)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A   B      C         D
0   C1  b1  10.20  0.827251
1   C1  b2  11.20  0.908354
2   C1  b3  13.12  1.064071
3   C1  b4  11.90  0.965126
4   C1  b5  12.33  1.000000
5   C1  b6  43.90       NaN
6   V2  b1  54.08  1.492686
7   V2  b2  42.99  1.186586
8   V2  b3  43.65  1.204803
9   V2  b4  36.23  1.000000
10  V2  b5  12.23       NaN
```